# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheck Error in using Angular Component

Tags: angular, components, lifecycle

I have created a date-picker component in my Angular app. When i use it inside *ngIf, I got error ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheck.
Let,I am using two component P and C.
P as parent Input field.

```
<INPUT [p]=" '' ">
```

C as child drop-down appends after INPUT.

```
<DIV>
// drop-down code
</DIV>
```

When P is created dynamically inside *ngIf, I got such error ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A running Angular application is a tree of components. During change detection Angular performs checks for each component which consists of the following operations performed in the specified order:

1. update bound properties for all child components/directives
2. call ngOnInit, OnChanges and ngDoCheck lifecycle hooks on all child
   components/directives
3. update DOM for the current component
4. run change detection for a child component
5. call ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook for all child
   components/directives

After each operation Angular remembers what values it used to perform an operation. They are stored in the oldValues property of the component view. After the checks have been done for all components Angular.

So at the end, We need to make it synchronous for Angular and to solve it we use [setTimeout inside lifecycle hooks.](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

```
ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
    // Your Code
    });
}
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
    // Your Code
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there an alternative to setTimeout as it feels super messy?

Comment: @uex then you can use zone.js callbacks.

Comment: Thanks, to make testing easier, I decided to use `ChangeDetectorRef`'s `detectChanges` function.